# Error AWR Operation failed: CATPROC not valid when creating database with dbca

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, installation

I have a fresh installation of Oracle 11g enterprise edition on CentOS 6, both 64 bits. I have installed Oracle and so far everything looks fine. I have already added an started a listener. The problem I have now is when I try to create a test db using `dbca`. Everything goes well until the post creation DB part which popups an error. The error shows the same text as the `/opt/app/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/testingDB/postDBCreation.log`:

```
   utl_recomp_begin: 09:34:38 
   utl_recomp_end: 09:34:42
   BEGIN dbms_swrf_internal.cleanup_database(cleanup_local => FALSE); END;

  *
  ERROR at line 1:
  ORA-13516: AWR Operation failed: CATPROC not valid
  ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SWRF_INTERNAL", line 206
  ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SWRF_INTERNAL", line 239
  ORA-06512: at line 1
```

The creation of the DB cannot continue and it stops here...

I have searched everywhere in internet but not luck so far. I have no clues what it can be. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Try to rerun `CATPROC` on the database while connected as `sys`:

```
@?/rdbms/admin/catproc.sql
```

The recompile all invalid objects:

```
@?/rdbms/admin/utlrp.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not include any spaces or special characters in the sys and other account password.[image]

Answer (score 0):

ORA-13516 DURING DB CREATION WHEN DB PWD CONTAINS " " (SPACE) CHARACTER Bug ID 8633879

Solution

Do not include any spaces or special characters in the password,

If you are particular with the passwords, then you can reset the passwords once the database is created. Eg:

conn / as sysdba

alter user USERNAME identified by PWD;